# “Warning: In norm::prelim.norm(data) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range” while using mcar_test in naniar package

Tags: r, missing-data, naniar

I am trying to run an MCAR test using the naniar package in R. I have a dataset with 52 variables (most of these responses to items on likert type scales). I am getting the warning "Warning: In norm::prelim.norm(data) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range". I tried changing the data types, and running the test on subsets of data frames. I am not getting the warning when I run the test on a smaller number of variables but when I increase it to about 31 columns is when the error shows up. This lead me to conclude that it's likely not a specific column that is causing the problem. Is this warning ignorable? Can i proceed with the interpreting the results despite it? or is there any other way to address it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `naniar::mcar_test()` function is based on the `prelim.norm` function in the `norm` package which **can handle about 30 variables**.

There is an extensive description of this issue in the `misty::na.test()`
help file (which is also based on `prelim.norm`.

> Note that the `mcar_test` function in the `naniar` package is also
> based on the `prelim.norm` function which results are not trustworthy
> whenever the following warning message is pronted on the console: In
> norm::prelim.norm(data) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
>
> With more than 30 variables specified in the argument x, the
> `prelim.norm` function might run into numerical problems leading to
> results that are not trustworthy. In this case it is recommended to
> reduce the number of variables specified in the argument x.

The recommend to use the `LittleMCAR` function in the `BaylorEdPsych` package which can deal with up to 50 variables. But you need to install this package from the [CRAN Archive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BaylorEdPsych/index.html), since it was archived some time ago. Which mean you have to install it manually. Maybe the MissMech package also works - but did not check this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. I had a suspicion it might be because of the number of variables but I was not able to find any information on this. This explains a lot.